# QT does not update UI

Tags: qt, qml

I have a very weird behavior for my QML pages. It used to be ok, but has changed recently. I have main.qml which uses a component from another file (for example, component.qml). So, when I update component.qml, nothing changes if I run mail.cpp. I have to comment and then immediately uncomment the line there I am using this component in main.qml, and only then it would change. Any solution for this?

Comment: Make sure, `qmake` runs every time. I see quite often, that this step is skipped unless I make changes in `main.qml`. Therefore I always add a custom build step in my projects.

Comment: Are you on Windows? It's probably https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-13334.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Windows, you're probably running into this really old, well-known bug that for some reason never gets fixed: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-13334

Update: it has apparently been fixed in Qt 5.14.